# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel will not open Excel Window

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a main method here that is simply trying to open an excel workbook. This same script works on other machines, but I can't get it to work on this machine. It starts a background EXCEL.exe process, but does not open an excel window.

If I end that process in the task manager, and then open excel, it shows the workbook in the mySheet string variable in the document recovery pane. So something opened. I just couldn't see it. What am I missing here?

Using a Console Application in Visual Studio 2017. Excel 2016 64 bit.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string mySheet = @"C:\\Users\\dwh002\\Documents\\ZIP_COUNTY_032017.xlsx";
            var excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
            excelApplication.Visible = true;
            var workbooks = excelApplication.Workbooks;
            var workbook = workbooks.Open(mySheet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Did you check if the process is running as the user in question? Not as run as admin, local system or stuff.

Comment: I'm running it within Visual Studio as myself (I am an administrator on my machine). Could not get any simpler than that. I have a similar script that opens an Outlook Mail window using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook assembly that works perfectly fine. Something tells me it's something wrong with the Interop.Excel assembly.

Comment: You could try a Console.ReadLine() at the end, to stop your app from closing maybe some unwanted clean up happens.

Comment: Simpler would be running your program from the command-line.  VS hides a lot of details from you.

Comment: Console.ReadLine(); did not work.

Comment: Try moving the `Visible = true` line after the `workbooks.Open` line. I frustratingly can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: The moving the Visible = true line worked. I'm not sure why this machine is the only one having trouble with the code in this order, but I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The moving the Visible = true line below the workbooks.Open line worked. I'm not sure why this machine is the only one having trouble with the code in this order, but I'm glad it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That also worked for me. but what's the reason ?